# .li hover and colorize .a and span

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want on hover to have for example red colored .a and span, and in my case it works if .a is hovered but if you hover on span arrow, only span arrow will be red.

```css
.menu li:hover {
  color: red;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item">
      <a href="">Blog</a>
      <span class="sub-menu-open">▲</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fgydznrx/

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO . :) ! Can we not tweak the HTML and the span be moved into the anchor tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need one more selector, when the li is hovered, select the `a` and color it too.

```
.menu li:hover>a {
  color: red;
}
```

## DEMO

```css
.menu li:hover {
  color: red;
}

.menu li:hover>a {
  color: red;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item">
      <a href="">Blog</a>
      <span class="sub-menu-open">▲</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: we no more need the third selector in this case

Comment: No we don't.­  ­­

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `<a>` element has its own style on hover, and you need to explictly overwrite it in order to get a different effect on hover.

In this case, you want its color to be the same of the parent. For this reason, you can apply `color: inherit` to achieve the result:

```css
.menu li:hover {
  color: red;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item">
      <a href="">Blog</a>
      <span class="sub-menu-open">▲</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```